How to convert long hex string into byte array (0x69, 0x63, etc. etc.)
I have a long hex string (around 8000 bytes) that I want to convert into what I think is called a byte array. (Please be kind if I've got the name wrong.) In other words, the string begins
69636E etc.
and I want a way to make this into a string that looks this in C source code:
0x69, 0x63, 0x6e, etc.
Is there a tool that can do this? I'm working in Windows but can also work in a Mac.
Ideally, it would break the resulting string with a newline after every 16 bytes, but I know I can do that by hand if needed.
My goal is to replace an existing string in some C code (from the source code for the Basilisk II classic-Mac emulator). The code I'm trying to replace is the long string beginning at line 113 in this file:
posix_emu.cpp

What language are you using? That byte array, is that array of strings in hex format as you provided or byte type?

Answered in an edit to the question - sorry, I should have spelled this out earlier.

Is it ok to use Python? Something like this might work: https://onecompiler.com/python/42khrsuek

I think that's the answer. Thank you! Will try it and report.

Works perfectly. To work with my long string, I had to download the code and run it from my disk, sending the output to a file. - This is EXACTLY what I needed. Many thanks again.

No problem. I wrote up an answer, so you can check it out.

Again, perfect. Thank you. Marked as answer.
